# Find all .txt files on PC, while excluding multiple paths in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to find all .txt files in all partitions, but I don't want to look in folders like C:\Windows, C:\PerfLogs, etc...

My code doesn't work.

```
$exl = ("*\PerfLogs\*","*\Program Files*","*\ProgramData\*","*\Windows\*",":\Python*");

foreach($i in (Get-PSDrive).Name -match '^[a-z]$'){ 
        foreach($item in (Get-ChildItem "${i}:\*.txt" -Recurse | Where {$_.FullName -notlike $exl})) { 
                echo $item.Fullname;}}
```

Please make my code resource-efficient. Make it skip the excluded folders alltogether without even recursing into them.

Whats weird is i run it with just 1 element, and it still doesnt work.

```
foreach($i in (Get-PSDrive).Name -match '^[a-z]$'){ foreach($item in (Get-ChildItem "${i}:\*.txt" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.FullName -NotLike "Windows"})) { echo $item.Fullname;}}
```

It still prints all txt files in C:\, it ignores the exception.

I tried with wildcards around the word *Windows* and without them, still the same result.

Also tried Where -NotContains, -NotIn....

Please run the command yourself and see for yourself

Comment: "please make my code x,y,z" is demanding we write code for you. And likely why you're being down voted. Stack overflow is designed to help those who try. Not write scripts for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **`-like` and `-notlike` operators only support a *single* pattern as the RHS, not an *array***<sup>[1]</sup>, so `$_.FullName -notlike $exl` won't work as you expect.
(It will convert array `$exl` to a single string by concatenating the array elements with a single space as the separator).

You can use the `switch` statement with the `-wildcard` option instead:

```
$driveRoots = (Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem).Root
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $driveRoots -Filter *.txt | Where-Object {
  switch -wildcard ($_.FullName) {
    '*\PerfLogs\*'     { break }
    '*\Program Files*' { break }
    '*\ProgramData\*'  { break }
    ':\Python*'        { break }
    default            { return $True } # doesn't match exclusion -> include
  }
  return $False # matches exclusion -> exclude
}
```

While this solution won't prevent recursing into folders that match the pattern, the use of the `-Filter` parameter greatly reduces the scanning effort by having the filesystem provider perform the initial filtering.

---

<sup>[1] There's a longstanding but languishing [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2132) to make `-like` / `-notlike` work with arrays of patterns too.</sup>

Comment: I never thought of this. Amazing logic. Thank you. I will likely put switches inside where now. Couldn't you just use "return $false" instead of break?

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful, @RobertCotterman. Yes, you can definitely stick the `return $False` statements directly in the branch code blocks; I went for DRY, but you could argue that it's not worth it here.

Comment: @mklement0 It works, thanks. But how do I make it do stuff to those files, like copy them?

Comment: Glad to hear it, @MyWays. To further process these files, append another pipeline segment; e.g., to copy, you'd append `... | Copy-Item -Destination $destPath` or, if you want to derive the destination path from the input path, `... | Copy-Item -Destination { <# code that processes $_, the input file object #> }`. `Get-Help Copy-Item -Online` will tell you more.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks. I've noticed that using copy-item inside the "default" bracket works too.

Comment: Yes, @MyWays, but the more typical, general pattern is to append another pipeline segment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain if this is the problem but if I recall a comma creates can array in PowerShell.

`,` Comma operator

As a binary operator, the comma creates an array. As a unary operator, the comma creates an array with one member. Place the comma before the member.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6

---

For troubleshooting purposes can you just try 1 directory, without any commas in your $exl variable?

Comment: I think the OP is aware that `$exl` contains an array; their misconception is presumably in expecting the `-like` operator to work with that array of patterns as the RHS, expecting the LHS to be matched against each pattern on the RHS. While that would indeed be handy, it isn't currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

Few observations:

```
-NotLike "Windows"  #you forgot *, this will only be false when item name is "Windows"
-notlike $exl # not like with array will always return true
```

try to use standard option for filtering (filter/exclude/include)

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path '~'  -Recurse -file  -Include *.txt -Exclude *anac*, *bz*
```

Although not sure if either built-in filter options or where operator will speed up execution, I think it will scan all files anyway. You may try just to loop thru folders (instead of recursive search) and skip those ones to avoid file scanning in them.

Comment: `-Exclude` only works on mere _filenames_, whereas the OP wants to match against the _full path_. While `-notlike` with an array won't work as intended - because the array's elements are stringified to a space-concatenated single string - it doesn't _always_ return `$True`, as the following example demonstrates: `'fo o' -notlike ('fo', 'o')`